# Prepared Statement in codeigniter php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, prepared-statement

```
SELECT answer into @a from progress where id = 1;
SELECT answer into @b from progress where id = 2;
SELECT answer into @c from progress where id = 3;

SET @query = CONCAT('select ?, ?, ', @c);
PREPARE stmt1 from @query;
EXECUTE stmt1 using @a, @b;
```

I would like to write the equivalent of this using the codeigniter model but I can't work out how to do it.

My database looks like this:

*table name:* **progress**

```
id  label_id  answer
1      1        5
2      2        10
3      3        @a+@b
```

*table name:* **master**

```
id   label
1      a
2      b
3      c
```

Can anyone suggest how this would be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Codeigniter doesn't support the SELECT INTO syntax

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter doesn't have any build in mechanic to execute a SELECT INTO statement. I've been working on a project in CodeIgniter too, I'm currently working on replacing the default database code (which they call activerecord for some reason) with PDO. The only way to do this is something along these lines

```
$query = "SELECT * INTO :table FROM somethingelse";
$query = str_replace(':table' , 'yourtablename', $query);
$this->db->query($query);
//.. rest of your code here
```

Comment: is it possible to use native php functions for executing multiple prepared statements

Comment: You should look at the PDO documentation it is a great way to talk to a database in small to large sized projects.